# Access and return private attribute in a function

Tags: php

I watch [this](https://youtu.be/OK_JCtrrv-c?t=15694) Tutorial about PHP, and in his video he is making an attribute to be `private`, means that we can't access it outside the `class`. But when he is creating a function that returns that `private` attribute, he is able to `echo` that attribute.

It's working for him, and for it just not printing anything

```
<?php
        class Book {
            private $rating;
            public $title;

            function __construct($title, $rating) {
                $this -> title = $title;
                $this -> rate = $rate;
            } 
            
            function getRating() {
                return $this -> rating;
            }
        }
        $book1 = new Book('Harry Potter', 'PG-13'); // object instance
        echo $book1 -> getRating(); // Does not print anything
?>
```

---

**Update**

I changed

```
$this -> rate = $rate;
```

To

```
$this -> rate = $rating;
```

But it is still doesn't print anything

Comment: `$this -> rate = $rate;`. This is a typo and you should be getting a message saying "Warning: Undefined variable $rate". Please double-check your error reporting settings.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't know why I don't get any debugging errors `php -S localhost:9000` on my web server (php web server).

Comment: Find your `php.ini` settings file and configure `error_reporting` and `display_errors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

Where did you get the **$rate** variable? It is basically used in nowhere. If $rating comes in, and $this->rating is the global variable, then there is no $rate variable.

There are also no spaces between `$this->title` and etc.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    
    // Use this function to make sure your error handling is tightest:
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    // Start a new class
    class Book {
        
        // We are setting the rating to be private:
        private $rating;
        
        // And we are setting the title to be public: You could also use 'var' here instead:
        var $title;
        
        // This is the function behind new Book () .. it is a construction function.
        function __construct ($title, $rating) {
            
            // You have $title coming and you are setting the classes global variable to it as well:
            $this->title = $title;
            
            // Same as above, but this is private, so outside of this class you cant access it:
            $this->rating = $rating;
        } 
        
        // This the function to get the rating:
        function getRating () {
            
            // This is the variable from the 5th line now. It is in fact private, but since the
            // function is inside the class, then this function getRating is allowed to access the variable
            // there for it will print it out without problems:
            return $this->rating;
        }
    }
    
    // Init the class and insert some basic information:
    $book1 = new Book('Harry Potter', 'PG-13');
    
    // Will print out 'PG-13'
    echo $book1->getRating() . '<br>';
    
    // Title will show up, as it is public:
    echo $book1->title . '<br>';
    
    // But accessing the rating directly, will not show anything:
    echo $book1->rating . '<br>';
    
    // Since the rating is private, then it will ultimate throw an error,
    // so this will kill the script or show the error, depending on your hosting settings:
    echo 'This probably wount show up';
    // yup, it gives you:
    // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property Book::$rating in [.........]
?>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Hope this helps you move forward learning about more PHP.

Comment: While you are learning about classes, check out static variables in classes as well.

Comment: Thanks, but It still does not print anything for me. Also, what is the difference between with spaces or without ?

Comment: @harabatahat General syntax is without spaces, it looks better. But I guess if it doesn't give you an error, in whatever php version you are, then do whatever. But if you would work for me, I would tell you to remove the spaces -- Ive never seen anyone do that.

Comment: @harabatahat You should be seeing PG-13 as getRating function is inside the class. I will update the example a bit, so you would understand better

Comment: If its still not showing anything, then you have an error somewhere else. Maybe in the php setup or something.

Comment: It looks like magic can happen sometimes. Especiallly with php... Good to know that you solved your problem. However I definitely advise you to investigate on the origins of the probem. COPY/PASTING this piece of code is not the solution and I bet that the problem will happen again ;). Welcome again and good luck!

Comment: @bousof Thank you. The problem was that the  web server took too long to save and show the output. Thank you for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor `__construct` you should be doing something like:

```
$this -> rating = $rating;
```

Not:

```
$this -> rate = $rate;
```

Comment: With the above corretion, your example is working just fine for me. Did the previous examples worked for you? Have you already been able to echo something in a php tag  before this? I wasn't able to find the reason unfortunately, please share it once you'll have solved your probem.